# If statement multiple conditions checking

Tags: php, arrays

Could you help me about problem with overwriting $tpl variable (remain only last foreach iteration data) in  if loop which is nested in foreach. If I remove nested if loop (only foreach loop remain)  the whole tv programme is is listed on page.  My goal is to display  tv programme  by day through choosing one of tree input type="submit".  The code is splitted in two file, xml2array.php and tv_schedule.php. Thank's in advance.

Below is tv_schedule.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <form id="select" action="" method="get" >
            <input type="submit" name="program" value="today" />
            <input type="submit" name="program" value="tomorrow" />
            <input type="submit" name="program" value="afterTomorrow" />
        </form>

        <table id="program" class="table tablesorter">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>beginning</th>
                    <th>end</th>
                    <th>programme</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php
        include_once('xml2array.php');
        $today = date('l');
        $tomorrow = date('l', strtotime("+1 day"));
        $afterTomorrow = date('l', strtotime("+2 day"));

        if(isset($_GET['program'])) {
            $select=$_GET['program'];
            if($select == 'Today' OR 'today') {
                $select = $today;
            }
            if($select == 'Tomorrow' OR 'tomorrow') {
                $select = $tomorrow;
            }
            if($select == 'AfterTomorrow' OR 'afterTomorrow') {
                $select = $afterTomorrow;
            }               
            foreach($programXml['programme'] AS $schedule) {
                //critical if loop
                if(date('l', strtotime($schedule['start'])) == $select) {
                    $tpl = "<tr>";
                    $tpl .= "<td>". date('H:i', strtotime($schedule['start']))."</td>";
                    $tpl .= "<td>". date('H:i', strtotime($schedule['stop']))."</td>";
                    $tpl .= "<td>".$schedule['content']['title'][0]['content']."</td>";
                    $tpl .= "</tr>";
                    echo $tpl;
                }// end if
            } // end foreach
        } //end if(isset($_POST['program']))

        ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

**EDIT** first code snippet xml2array.php works ok, second code tv_schedule.php, if(date('l', strtotime($schedule['start'])) == $select) {...} is main problem. Sorry for misleading.

Comment: The first block of code doesn't even have a variable `$tpl`!

Comment: First block still doesn't have a variable `$tpl`. My point is the first block seems irrelevant to the question, which is also not clear by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you're saying that the code in the `if` statement (`if` is not a loop, by the way) is not executed? Then it's probably because the condition it checks is false.

The reason is probably in the code above the loop. This condition is wrong:

```
if($select == 'Today' OR 'today') {
    $select = $today;
}
```

It should (probably) be:

```
if ($select == 'Today' or $select == 'today') {
    $select = $today;
}
```

Same goes for the other similar conditions in that piece of code. This error causes `$select` to have a different value than expected. This is by the way something you can have easily discovered using some poor man's debugging, ie, by `var_dump`ing the values you compare in your `if` condition.